# Is it possible to move "Display name" out of standard fields?

Tags: link-manager

I want to configure my Link Manager to utilize the Display Name field when generating URLs, like so:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
      <providers>
        <add name="sitecore">
          <patch:attribute name="useDisplayName">true</patch:attribute>
        </add>
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

However, that Display Name field is down in the standard fields and hard to manage from an authoring point of view.  I'd like to move it up higher in my page templates.  Is this possible?

Alternatively, can I configure the link manager to use my own custom field instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you may be switched around in your thinking.

The display name field is used to when you view the item in sitecore you are able to have it look better compared to the actual item name.

If you want to have urls created to look a certain way, it would be best to use the item name when you create the item to be the url you want and then fill out the display name so it looks better in the content tree.

You can edit the display name using the tab on the content editor. [image: Display Name and Rename button]

Comment: If I have a page in english called "one", I want the URL to be www.mysite.com/one.  That same page in german, however, should be www.mysite.com/ein.  I thought I could use the Display Name to achieve this?

Comment: you would use a page alias for this sort of behaviour on the  "Presentation" tab there should be an Alias button.

Comment: Yep, didn't realize that button was there! This will do, as my content authors can utilize that.  Thanks!

Comment: If you set display name for each language version, you can achieve it, if you add "sc_lang" parameter. www.mysite.com/ein/?sc_lang=de-DE or www.mysite.com/de-DE/ein